# Where is the current install source for opencv4tegra?

Tags: opencv

As you know NVidia was providing native binaries to run on the Jetson (with proprietary optimization of the library for their Tegra SoC).  Now they have removed the link saying a new version is "coming soon".  Any idea where I can find the old version?  If you have it, can you post it somewhere? Were you able to successfully install it and use it?

My other option is to compile opencv on the jetson (slow), or cross-compile on another Ubuntu machine ( I have little experience with this).

Answer (score 1):

You can compile opencv on the jetson and remove it when the new version available.